# In Javascript and/or jQuery how can I get the first line of text in a wrapped div

Tags: javascript, html, css, word-wrap

I want to get the first line of the text contents of a div where the text has been wrapped on to several lines by the browser due to div's styling which only shows the first row.  Here is the HTML div and the styling used to hide all but the first line:

```
<div id="element"
     style="display: inline-block; height: 20px; overflow: hidden;
            width: 70px;">asdfl asf af adf adsf dsaf adsf adsfdsa fdsaf dsa fdas fdsa f dsaf dsa fdsa f dsaf sad</div>
```

The text within the div is not pre-wrapped, the  and  tags and the contained text are all on the same line (as shown), there are no embedded new-lines (\n), and the font is not fixed (so counting characters within the string won't work).

When I inspect the div's, the innerHTML and innerText both contain:

```
"asdfl asf af adf adsf dsaf adsf adsfdsa fdsaf dsa fdas fdsa f dsaf dsa fdsa f dsaf sad"
```

For this example, I want to only get 'asdfl asf' after any trailing spaces have been trimmed, if there are any.

The heart of the issue is to be able to get the string as the browser wrapped it.

Comment: That would require the div useful width abd font size to calcuate hiw long the line can be, than getting the portion of the string that can fit in.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get first line you need remove all text and in loop adding characters one by one and if text have height bigger then single character, then the previous character was the last one.

```
function get_first_line(element) {
    var original = element.text();
    element.text(original[0]);
    var height = element.height();
    var first = original;
    for (var i = 2; i < original.length; ++i) {
        element.text(original.slice(0, i));
        if (element.height() > height) {
            first = original.slice(0, i - 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    element.text(original);
    return first;
}
```

**EDIT** And here is working code with hyphens, the solution is to wrap each character in span, they are inline elements so they work the same as characters in term of wrapping.

```
function get_first_line(element) {
  var original = element.text();
  var text = original.trim();
  // if you care about IE change it to normal function
  element.html(text.split('').map((c) => '<span>' + c + '</span>'));
  var chars = element.find('span');
  var offset = chars.eq(0).offset();
  var first = original;
  for (var i = 1; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if (chars.eq(i).offset().top > offset.top) {
      first = text.slice(0, i);
      break;
    }
  }
  element.text(original);
  return first;
}
```

And codepen demo https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/erBRmb?editors=1010

Comment: I think you’re likely to encounter edge cases where it isn’t really as simply as that though. `Foooooooo-Baaaaaar` is likely to be broken into a second line by the browser at the hyphen when it doesn’t fit the line; but `Foooooooo-Baaaa` might have still fitted, so when you add the next `a` and then your script realizes the text starts to break, the previous character won’t be the one that still gets displayed on the previous line.

Comment: @CBroe maybe someone will came up with better solution.

Comment: Not saying it was “bad”, just that the issue is more complex than one might think initially ;-)

Comment: @CBroe created another solution by wrapping each character in span (wrapping work the same because characters are inline elements the same as spans).

Comment: Nice work, that’s worth a +1 now definitively. (Although soft hyphens can still pose a bit of a problem, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjozpO - but handling _those_ and the breaks they might cause as well, might get even more complex I suppose, so unless OP states that as an explicit requirement, probably not worth the bother.)

Comment: Thanks for all the help on this.  After posting this question, I came up with the manual wrap solution, too.  In my case, I wrap using words, defined by spaces, then fall-back to characters when words fail, and then use right-end truncation by characters when the first two methods fail.  I haven't looked at hyphens or special characters. So far my solution seems to work, but I will need to continue to check for special cases..  I look forward to any other input that gets posted, here.  It's too bad we can't query the browser for the individual lines after text is wrapped.    Again, thank you!